# Using a single cookie instead of two in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cookies

I am using two separate cookies in CakePHP to store two separate arrays:

```
$this->Cookie->write('first', $firstArray, true, '6 months');
$this->Cookie->write('second', $secondArray, true, '6 months');
```

The way I access the arrays stored in my cookies is by using this:

```
$firstArray = $this->Cookie->read('first');
$secondArray = $this->Cookie->read('second');
```

I want to put info for both in the same cookie in order to save some overhead. Any ideas about how to achieve this so that I can use a single cookie to store both arrays in CakePHP, and then access those values? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply nest the two arrays in a parent array. The data is stored as a JSON string, so the nesting/depth limit is whatever the default for JSON encoding/decoding is for your PHP installation.

```
$this->Cookie->write(
    'both',
    ['first' => $firstArray, 'second' => $secondArray],
    true,
    '6 months'
);
```

```
$firstArray = $this->Cookie->read('both.first');
$secondArray = $this->Cookie->read('both.second');
```

See also

- **[CakePHP 3 Cookbook > Controllers > Components > Cookie](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/cookie.html)**
- **[CakePHP 2 Cookbook > Core Libraries > Components > Cookie](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/cookie.html)**

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up implementing it:

```
//$variable1Array = $this->Cookie->read('variable1'); -----> BEFORE
$variable1Array = $this->Cookie->read('Box.variable1');  -----> NOW

//$variable2Array = $this->Cookie->read('variable2');  -----> BEFORE
$variable2Array = $this->Cookie->read('Box.variable2');  -----> NOW

//$this->Cookie->write('variable2', $variable2Array, true, '2 months');  -----> BEFORE
$this->Cookie->write('Box.variable2', $variable2Array, true, '2 months');  -----> NOW

//$this->Cookie->write('variable1', $variable1Array, true, '2 months');  -----> BEFORE
$this->Cookie->write('Box.variable1', $variable1Array, true, '2 months');  -----> NOW
```